# How to override checksum in a bbappend file in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I would like to override the checksum for a file without editing the actual bb file. I have my own meta layer and any way to write a bbappened file and can I override the checksum value?

The issue here is the original BB file contains bad checksum for the source file and I need to change it without editing the original file. But at the build time, bitbake should consider the new checksum which I have provided through the bbappend file via my own layer. Is there nay way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a `.bbappend` file in your own layer.
Just add

```
SRC_URI[md5sum] =
SRC_URI[sha256sum] =
```

in your bbappend-file.

However, you really should update the upstream layer, if the upstream tarball has had their checksum's changed.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this but the change didn't reflect during build time.